# How do I get jQuery waypoint plugin to count newly added content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am using waypoint plugin for jQuery. And it works perfectly for divs that are on the page. But when I add new divs using AJAX, it doesn't work on those newly added divs. It doesn't count them.

Here is my code:

```
Waypoint = $('.Picture-1A').waypoint(function(direction){
    if(direction == 'down'){
        id = $(this.element).children(".PictureID").text();
        $.post('ajax/count-pictures-views.php', {picture_id: id}, function(data){
            Waypoint.refreshAll();
        });
    }
});
```

I have also used On() but it didn't work for all, default and newly added.
How can I make it work for newly added content?

Here is my Ajax page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

endPictures = true;

scrollCount = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){

    if(endPictures == true){

    if(scrollCount == 0){

        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 3000){

        scrollCount = 1;

        picturesCount = $(".Picture-1A").length;

            $.post('ajax/load-latest.php', {off_set:picturesCount},  function(data){
                if(data){
                    $("#loadMore").append(data);
                    scrollCount = 0;
                }else{
                    $("#loadMore").append("<div class=\"NoMorePictures\"><center>There are no pictures left.</center></div><br/ >")
                    endPictures = false;
                    scrollCount = 0;
                }
            });

        }

    }

    }
});});
```

Comment: Can you show full details code how can added content ?

Comment: @user5200704 I have added the Ajax script. I think the problem is with `$.waypoints('refresh')`. I think that using this will solve the problem, but I don't know where to put it in the script.

Comment: you can add in ajax function when new content is added after use $.waypoints('refresh').

Comment: @user5200704 I have tried that, it didn't work. I think my problem is where should I add `refreshAll()`.

Comment: if(data){
                    $("#loadMore").append(data);
                    scrollCount = 0;
                  refreshAll()
                }

Comment: @user5200704 It didn't work. Isn't there should be something before `refreshAll()` like `$.waypoints.refreshAll()`. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: can you share html and also what data you get using ajax pls share

Comment: @user5200704 Thank you for your help. I have found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally come up with a solution. Here is the code I think it is self explanatory.

```
$.post('ajax/load-latest.php', {off_set:picturesCount},  function(data){
    if(data){
        $("#loadMore").append(data);
        scrollCount = 0;
        $('.Picture-1A').waypoint(function(direction){
            if(direction == 'down'){
                id = $(this.element).children(".PictureID").text();
                $.post('ajax/count-pictures-views.php', {picture_id: id}, function(data){

                });
            }
        });
    }else{
        $("#loadMore").append("<div class=\"NoMorePictures\"><center>There are no pictures left.</center></div><br/ >")
                    endPictures = false;
                    scrollCount = 0;
                }
            });
```

All I did was add the `$('.Picture-1A').waypoint(function(){});` to the infinite scroll ajax call. So every time the ajax call is triggered, the waypoint is refreshed.

Comment: This is correct, except you'll end up adding multiple waypoints to the previous `.Picture-1A` elements. You'll want to find only the ones that were newly added. Perhaps by setting a class on them once you've added a waypoint and skipping them with `:not`

Comment: @imakewebthings No. It works great. It doesn't count them twice. I have tested. But thank you for your reply :) and thank you for this plugin.